# IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Out of the blue I started getting “IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch” in hibernate. The hibernate entity was working for quite some time and svn logs confirm the code to be intact.

What might be the case?
Here’s part of the exception

```
Jan 16, 2010 10:47:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter.set(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3566)
    at org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:854)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:729)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:930)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:419)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:921)
```

Comment: Any changes to a database table?

Comment: Still you may want to inspect your .hbm files to see any of those changes overlap?

Comment: @Kaleb u r right. Addition of this code to the hbm created this error
`<set inverse="true" name="qs" sort="unsorted" lazy="false">
            <key>
                <column name="q_id" not-null="false"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.comp.domain.Q" />
        </set>`
Do u have any idea why it might be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Translation: Hibernate provides an argument of wrong type when trying to invoke a setter method.

My first step would be to find out which setter that is (for instance by debugging the application in eclipse, setting an exception break point, and inspecting the stack variables once the breakpoint is reached).

Edit: What is the signature of the setter for the mapped property `qs`? It should take a `Set<Q>`.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is the use of "**addScalar**" in your query execution.

Suppose your Entity is a user :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
@DynamicUpdate(value=true)
public class UserEntity implements Serializable{    

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id",updatable=false)
private Long id;

@Column(name="name",nullable=false,length=20)
private String name;
....
}
```

Instead of doing :

```
List<UserEntity> users = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
      .createQuery(query)
      .list();
```

Use addScalar :

```
List<UserEntity> users = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
     .createQuery(query)
     .addScalar("id",LongType.INSTANCE)
     .addScalar("name",StringType.INSTANCE)         
     .list();
```

**Note** : prior to LongType.INSTANCE, there was Hibernate.LONG and Hibernate.STRING (they are deprecated now).

Answer (score 3):

I've heard of this happening due to underlying database field changes (such as date to timestamp).  It might be worth reverting the database changes if you're able and testing it, or checking the .hbm or annotations as Sands suggested.

Comment: @Kaleb u r right. Addition of this code to the hbm created this error `<set inverse="true" name="qs" sort="unsorted" lazy="false"> <key> <column name="q_id" not-null="false"/> </key> <one-to-many class="com.comp.domain.Q" /> </set>` Do u have any idea why it might be?

Answer (score 3):

So, you modified an hibernate mapping file without modifying the Entity? I guess that the `qs` property was already there then. But is it a `java.util.Set` (as you used a `<set>` to [map your collection](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-mapping))?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happened when the types are not compatible. For MySQL query following conversion of casting must be made for compatibility.

```
select CAST(sum(hours) AS SIGNED) ...
```

Hope this will help the people run into the similar problem with JPA(JPA-Hibernate for exact).